# Aligning text in kableExtra table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am making a Latex pdf in R markdown but am having problems making tables that contain text with the kableExtra package.

When I use the 'align =' argument in Kable() it aligns only the headings and not the full text. The table returned looks like what is below, with the first row of main body aligned left, the next row centre aligned, and the last row right aligned!!

Please help me get it all centre aligned!

[Table that gets produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpopo.png)

Code:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(c("Title","Title", "Title"), 
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")))

kable(df, align="c", col.names = c("","Title","Title", "Title"), escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options="HOLD_position")
```

EDIT:

Here is the reproduced code with yaml,

```
---
title: 
author: 
date:
abstract:
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
  editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(c("Title","Title", "Title"), 
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text")))

kable(df, align="c", col.names = c("","Title","Title", "Title"), escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options="HOLD_position")
```

Comment: Do you mean `align="l"` l for left  instead of `align="c"` c for central?

Comment: Sorry yes I do, but either way I am confused as to why with `align = "c"` in place some cells right align, some left align and some are centre aligned?

Comment: In my Viewer output I can't reproduce this issue. Is you picture the pdf output or the output in the Viewer?

Comment: The picture is the pdf output I think? As in the pdf that is generated when I press knit. (Sorry I am new to this).

Comment: We need the complete markdown code to help!

Comment: What do you mean by the complete code? The code for the whole document is over 3000 lines long!

Comment: OK I see. Then try a new dummy markdown document with your yaml and r```....``` chuck with your problem code. Try to reproduce the behaviour and post the minimal reproducible example of markdown code! NO need for 3000 lines. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the specification of your `df`. Function `linebreak` has an `align` argument that is being set when you are creating `df`. You need to specify the alignment when creating `df`

```
df <- data.frame(c("Title","Title", "Title"), 
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text"), align = 'c'),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text"), align = 'c'),
                linebreak(c("The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text", "The Main Text\n Main Text\n Text"), align = 'c'))
```

Also, following [documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) from `kableExtra` it is recommended to add `booktabs = T` and `escape = F` when working with LaTex tables. E.g.:

```
df %>% kbl(booktabs = T, escape = F,
  col.names = c("","Title","Title", "Title"), align = 'c')
```